# Add FadeIn/Out after Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a transition effect whenever the mouse enters & exits a box. http://jsfiddle.net/q6jpjz65/6/

The fade in & out transition effect would be between each div involving .info1, .info2, .info3, & .headline.

I have tried putting the transition directly in the CSS as well as in the JS section with .transition & .setAttribute. But these did not cause a transition to occur even with different opacities.

I also attempted to apply it kind of like it is here, but got stuck since this involves a third div, the .headline div. http://jsfiddle.net/q186sksn/

Is this possible with the transition attribute? Or no since there are so many layers with hide/unhide events?

```
    .headline {
        display: block;
    }
    .info1 {
        display: none;
    }
    .info2 {
        display: none;
    }
    .info3 {
        display: none;
    }
    #box1, #box2, #box3 { 
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
        width: 1.92708%; 
        height: 3.7871%;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid white;
        outline: 1px solid black;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #box1:hover #box2 #box3 {
        opacity: 0.2; 
    }
    #box1:hover .info1 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box1:hover .headline {
        display: none;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box2:hover #box1 #box3 {
        opacity: 0.2; 
    }
    #box2:hover .info2 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box2:hover + .headline {
        display: none;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box3:hover #box1 #box2 {
        opacity: 0.2; 
    }
    #box3:hover .info3 {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #box3:hover + .headline {
        display: none;
        opacity: 1; 
    }





    <div class="headline">
          This text is always displayed when nothing is hovered.
    </div>
    <div id="box1" style="top: 10%">
        <div class="info1">
        Information for box1.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" style="top: 30%">
        <div class="info2">
        Information for box2.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" style="top: 50%">
        <div class="info3">
        Information for box3.
        </div>
    </div>

    document.getElementById("box1").onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("info1")[0].style.display = "block";
        for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
            if(i != 1) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.2";
            if(i == 1) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "1";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("box1").onmouseout = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("info1")[0].style.display = "none";
        for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
            if(i != 1) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 2) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 3) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 4) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
        }
    }



    document.getElementById("box2").onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("info2")[0].style.display = "block";
        for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
            if(i != 2) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.2";
            if(i == 2) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "1";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("box2").onmouseout = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("info2")[0].style.display = "none";
        for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
            if(i != 1) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 2) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 3) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 4) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
        }
    }



    document.getElementById("box3").onmouseover = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("info3")[0].style.display = "block";
        for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
            if(i != 3) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.2";
            if(i == 3) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "1";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("box3").onmouseout = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("headline")[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName("info3")[0].style.display = "none";
        for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
            if(i != 1) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 2) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 3) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
            if(i != 4) document.getElementById("box"+i).style.opacity = "0.4";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the css `transition` attribute as follows in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luhjkxu9/)? I believe this is the desired effect (let me know if this isn't so).

It seems to work fine after adding `transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out` into the css and tweaking the javascript.

Comment: Yeah I tried both, but I didn't try it with the opacity in the JS. "Duh" moment for me :P. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be like 1000 times easier? 
http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/a0my545L/4/

HTML

```
<div id="mypic"><img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" /></div>
```

CSS

```
div{width: 400px;}
#mypic {
  position:relative;
  max-width:100%;
}

#mypic img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  opacity:0.2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

#mypic img.top:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```